# keep scroll position when clicking on next page for category view M1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, category-view

I am wanting to stop the page from returning on the top when a customer clicks on the pagination buttons for the category view pages.

I have content at the top of the page for the category description and although it is good to have for seo and information, once read it is annoying to constantly have to scroll back through it to get the next page of products up.

Is there a way to keep the page stick to the top of the products section on this page? ie similar to a sticky position?

Any help or direction to an old post would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an ID to the product listing container and append that to the URL on the pagination resulting in something like `<a href="/your-category.html#listing-container">1</a>`

Because of the ID in the URL the browser will anchor the user to the products, and because only the pagination links contain this it won't affect users loading the page from other sources.